# How to get a random float with step in Python

Tags: python, random, floating-point

Still trying to figure out if there is a function in Python to get a random float value with step? Similar to randrange(start, stop, step) but for floats.

Answer (score 10):

```
import random

def randrange_float(start, stop, step):
    return random.randint(0, int((stop - start) / step)) * step + start

randrange_float(2.1, 4.2, 0.3) # returns 2.4
```

Comment: Using `int(round(...))` may be a little safer than using `int(...)`, especially if it'll usually be the case that `stop - start` is close to a multiple of `step`.  Otherwise it's difficult to predict whether `stop` will be a possible value or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply for some appropriate constant in order to get integers and reverse the operation over the result.

```
start = 1.5
stop  = 4.5
step  = 0.3
precision = 0.1
f = 1 / precision
random.randrange(start*f, stop*f, step*f)/f
```